# How to determine GPS getting unlocked while running the application in android?

Tags: android, gps, locking, unlock

I need to check whether GPS is locked in my application. I am able to check whether GPs is enabled in the phone. But once the GPS is locked, while running the application, it gets unlocked and I noticed that the GPS icon of the phone is blinking. I need to show an animation similar to that of phone in my application to acknowledge the user the GPS is unlocked. Anybody who knows the solution please post it.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15918158/1168654

Comment: maybe this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html

Comment: Thanks Dhaval, 
Actually I don't want to turn on and off GPS. That's is done and the application is running fine. What I need is that, I need to check whether the GPS is getting off occasionally. Some times you may also notice that the GPS i con in android is blinking after getting locked. I need to check this and if the android GPS icon is blinking I need to display a similar icon blinking in my application.

Comment: The icon is blinking when it is searching for your location. The icon will stop blinking when it has a lock on your location. @ookami.kb's link should provide you with an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. Start your animation when you `requestLocationUpdates` and end it when you get the `onLocationChanged` call. See my code below, it should solve your issue.

```
public class YourLocationClass implements LocationListener {
    private LocationManager lm;

    public void getLocation(Context ctx) {
        lm = (LocationManager)  ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 15000, 25, this);

        //START YOUR ANIMATION
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //HERE YOU STOP YOUR ANIMATION AND GET NEW LOCATION
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // DO SOME STUFF

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // DO SOME STUFF

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // DO SOME STUFF
    }

}
```